# Express & Node JS - Getting undefined when using findOne or findById

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a microservice that takes care of sending random OTP codes by email.

here is my findbyattr endpoint:

```
router.get('/findbyattr/:email', async (request, response) =>{
    try {
        let requestEmail = request.params.email; //it works -> i get the email
        let myOTPCode = await otpCodeModel.findOne({email:requestEmail}); //getting undefined here
        response.status(202).json(code);
    }catch(error){
        response.status(400).json({ErrorMessage: `Error: ${error}`});
    }
});
```

**My question is:**

In the **findbyattr** endpoint, in the following line:

```
let myOTPCode = await otpCodeModel.findOne({email:requestEmail});
```

I am getting undefined, what is the reason ?

Comment: What's it saying is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `findbyemail` endpoint to this:

```
router.get('/findbyemail/:email', async (request, response) =>{
    try {
        let requestEmail = request.params.email;
        let myOTPModel = await otpCodeModel.findOne({email: requestEmail});
        let code = myOTPModel.otpCode;
        response.status(202).json(code);
    }catch(error){
        response.status(400).json({ErrorMessage: `Error: ${error}`});
    }
});
```